# How to disable JButton after timer countdown to 0

Tags: java, timer

I'm doing a clicking game program. User has to key in the time limit (in secs). If the value is positive then the click button would be enabled. When time runs out, the click button would be disabled. This is part of my current code:
I can't seem to use the value returned from setInterval() and disable my Click button after the timer hits 0.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
     if (a.getSource()==startButton){
            try{
                    String sec = timeField.getText();
                    int delay = 1000;
                    int period = 1000;
                    timer = new Timer();
                    interval = Integer.parseInt(sec);

                    if(interval > 0){
                        timeLeft.setText("Time left: " + sec);
                          timeLeft.setText("Start!");
                          clickButton.setEnabled(false);



                        if(setInterval() > 0){
                            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                public void run() {
                                      timeLeft.setText("Time left: " + String.valueOf(setInterval()));
                                    }
                                }, delay, period);

                            clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                        }else{
                            System.out.print(String.valueOf(setInterval()));
                            clickButton.setEnabled(false);  
                            }

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error! Please enter postivie Interger! ", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error! Please enter Integer! ", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
     else if(a.getSource()==clickButton)
     {
         clickCOunter++;
         clickLabel.setText("Clicks: " + clickCOunter);
     }
}

 private static final int setInterval() {
        if (interval == 1)
            timer.cancel();
        return --interval;
    }
```

Comment: Is this line executed repeatedly as expected? timeLeft.setText("Time left: " + String.valueOf(setInterval()));

Comment: yes it countdowns as a timer

Answer (score 1):

In your case now, I would place a System.out.println(setInterval()); right above the `if(setInterval() > 0) {` check. That way you could observe how the value changes better.

As a general tip, you don't have to use `String.valueOf(...)` to print numbers. Removing it will also make your code easier to read.
Also, make sure to line up your curly braces ( { } ). This will also make your code easier to read and debug.

Last of all, if I may make a suggestion would to take a slightly simpler aproach to your problem. If you use the Swing timer, you can create it outside of the `actionPerformed()` method, and set it up to call `actionPerformed()` at regular intervals. This way the logic inside `actionPerformed()` could be simplified quite a bit.
Please take a look at the documentation for the Swing timer.[Swing Timer docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)